# How to sort array and take 5 items only?

Tags: php

How to get only 5 newest articles from array?

For example:

```
  usort($articles, function ($item1, $item2) {
        return $item2['created_at'] <=> $item1['created_at'];
    });
```

This will sort them descending and I don't need to show all of them.

What would be the best way to do this? Is it possible without looping again and storing in new array?

Comment: If you get items from DB - use `limit` and `order by` in query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) on the sorted array should do.

```
usort($articles, function ($item1, $item2) {
    return $item2['created_at'] <=> $item1['created_at'];
});

$fiveFirst = array_slice($articles, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first parameter be array... and usort returns bool... This is what I get `array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given`

Comment: mmm.. Fixed my answer ;)